# Map values from multiple dbContexts to ViewModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I have 3 databases: `Administration` -> with table `ResourceText`, there are all string values in multiple applications,
`Farm` -> there are two `CodeBooks`, for `Towns` and `DCCounty`. These 2 databases are shared across multiple applications. Beside them, there is database `HuntersApplication`, which I use for my application.

I 'll use `DCCounty` for this example.

So, I generated 3 `DbContexts`, for 3 different databases.
Entity `DCCounty` from `Farm` db looks like:

```
namespace Domain.FarmEntities;

public partial class Dccounty
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

public int EntityId { get; set; }

public int NameResourceId { get; set; }

public int? DescriptionResourceId { get; set; }

public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

public bool Active { get; set; }

public int CountyType { get; set; }
}
```

Entity `ResourceText` from `Administration` db is:

```
namespace Domain.AdministrationEntities;

public partial class ResourceText
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }

    public int CultureId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And finally, entity `Exam` from 'HuntingApplication` DB:

```
public partial class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ExamPlaceCountyId { get; set; }
    //other fields
}
```

Now, I want to write service that after some filtering, it return `ExamTableViewModel` with names instead of numbers for ID.

```
  public class GetAllExamsBySearchQuery : BasePaginationModel, IRequest<PagedResponse<ExamTableViewModel>>
{
    public DateTime? ExamDateFilter { get; set; }
    public int? ExamPlaceFilter { get; set; }
    public int? ExamPlaceCountyFilter { get; set; }
    public int? HuntingAssociationFilter { get; set; }
    public bool? StatusFilter { get; set; }
}

public class GetAllExamsBySearchHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllExamsBySearchQuery, PagedResponse<ExamTableViewModel>>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IAdministrationDbContext _administrationContext;
    private readonly IFarmDbContext _farmContext;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public GetAllExamsBySearchHandler(IApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper, IAdministrationDbContext administrationContext, IFarmDbContext farmContext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _administrationContext = administrationContext;
        _farmContext = farmContext;
    }

    public async Task<PagedResponse<ExamTableViewModel>> Handle(GetAllExamsBySearchQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var data = _context.Set<Exam>()
        .Where(x => (request.StatusFilter == null || x.Status == request.StatusFilter)
                    && (request.ExamDateFilter == null || x.ExamDate == request.ExamDateFilter)
                    && (request.ExamPlaceFilter == null || x.ExamPlaceId == request.ExamPlaceFilter)
                    && (request.ExamPlaceCountyFilter == null || x.ExamPlaceCountyId == request.ExamPlaceCountyFilter)
                    && (request.HuntingAssociationFilter == null || x.HuntingAssociationId == request.HuntingAssociationFilter)).AsQueryable();

        List<ResourceText> resource =await _administrationContext.Set<ResourceText>().Where(x => x.CultureId == 1).ToListAsync();
        List<Dccounty> cantons = await _farmContext.Set<Dccounty>().Where(x => request.ExamPlaceCountyFilter==null || x.Id == request.ExamPlaceCountyFilter).ToListAsync();

            var dataTableViewModel = await data
            .ProjectTo<ExamTableViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, new { resources = resource, cantons =cantons})
            .PaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);

        return dataTableViewModel;
    }
}
```

}

My `ExamTableViewModel` looks like:

```
   {
        public class ExamTableViewModel : IMapFrom<Exam>
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }
            public string ExamPlace { get; set; }
            public string ExamPlaceCounty { get; set; }
            public string HuntingAssociation { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
    
            public static void Mapping(Profile profile)
            {
                List<ResourceText>? resources = null;
                List<Dccounty>? cantons = null;
                profile.CreateMap<Exam, ExamTableViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.HuntingAssociation, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.HuntingAssociation.Name))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Status ? "Završen" : "U toku"))
                    .ForMember(d => d.ExamPlace, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest,_,context) =>
                    {
                        var cantonNameId = cantons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == src.ExamPlaceCountyId).NameResourceId;
                        return resources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResourceId == cantonNameId).Value;
                    }));
                 
            }
        }
    }
```

To get name of `DcCounty`, I need to take `HunterApplication.Exam.ExamPlaceCountyId`, find in table `Farm.DcCounty` row with that `ID`, get `NameResourceID` from that row, and then find in table `Administration.ResourceText` row with that `ID`, and return it's `Value`.

Problem is with multiple `dbContexts`. If I send multiple `contexts` to mapper, I get error
`Can't use multiple instances of DbContext for single query`. That's why I tried to get two lists, for these two tables, but I don't know how to properly use them in `Mapping` function.

Currently, I get error:
 `"Unable to create a map expression from . (Domain.Entities.Exam) to String.ExamPlace (System.String)\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nExam -> ExamTableViewModel\r\nDomain.Entities.Exam -> Application.BusinessLogic.Exams.Queries.ViewModels.ExamTableViewModel\r\n\r\nType Map configuration:\r\nExam -> ExamTableViewModel\r\nDomain.Entities.Exam -> Application.BusinessLogic.Exams.Queries.ViewModels.ExamTableViewModel\r\n\r\nDestination Member:\r\nExamPlace\r\n"`

Comment: IMHO, this is perfect sample when do not use Automapper. Project everything by `Select` by yourself. How `resources` and `cartoons` are related to each other? Also there is useless usage of `PaginatedList`.

Comment: I use paginated list to send data to frontend. there is no direct relationship, but in `cantons` is `NameResourceID`, which is PK in `resources`